# Word to be used for "standing with your toes pointing out"

Tags: word-usage

[image]

If someone is standing this way, what should be used:

> Don't stand with your feets out.
>
> Don't stand with your feets angled out
>
> Don't stand with your feet sticking outward
>
> Don't stand with your feet pointing outward.

Source:http://posturedirect.com/how-to-fix-duck-feet-posture/

Comment: Where did you get the image from?

Comment: Why? Is something wrong with this picture @James K ?

Comment: The image is fine, but it is also probably copyright. It is polite to at least say where you took it from. Or if you made it yourself, then you can say so.

Comment: Um...... I didn't mean to be rude. But if I sounded rude,well..... sorry for that.

Comment: You didn't say anything rude.  But you should [edit] to say where you got the image from.

Answer (score 4):

It's often called being [***duck-footed***](https://heelthatpain.com/duck-footed-out-toeing/) or ***splay-footed***...

> *As children grow, parents are often concerned about their feet pointing **inwards** when they walk (also called in-toe or **pigeon-toed** walking) or **outwards** (also called out-toe walking or **duck-footed**).*

Note that ***splay-footed*** is also used to mean that the toes are more "spread out", not necessarily that the feet themselves point more "outwards".

The walking gait of someone whose feet turn outwards is also likely to be referred to as ***waddling*** (typically used *specifically* of how ducks themselves walk), but that term can also refer to the way a ***bow-legged*** person walks (stereotypically, an old-time cowboy who's spent too many years sitting in a saddle, forcing his legs apart).

Comment: 'Duck-footed' is much more common than 'slue-footed', but I prefer 'penguin-toed'.

Answer (score 3):

Well, firstly the plural of ***foot*** is ***feet***. No 's'.

The nearest of those to unambiguously mean what you want is the fourth. The first (ignoring the obvious error) could mean a number of things in different contexts. The second, ignoring the same error, might be very likely to result in people understanding you, but it doesn't sound like anything someone would say. The third is jarringly close to "your feet sticking out", which means something else.

Comment: I asked someone and that person said that the fourth option doesn't sound natural.(though I have read it at a lot of places)  But what would you use anyway?

Comment: And does this sentence sound natural: Why are you standing with your feet pointing outward?

Comment: I'd call it "feet turned out", but I know that would be taken differently (and as being fairly surreal) in some other dialects. Or "duck footed", but that's again a bit dialect-limited.

Comment: And what about:And does this sentence sound natural: Why are you standing with your feet pointing outward? –

Answer (score 2):

I googled some and found the adjective **duck-footed**:

> [Duck-footed](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duck-footed): Having splayfoot; habitually standing or walking with the ends of the feet angled outward

Wikipedia provides the following example of usage: "Texas Southern's Jim Hines, 20, is not the least bit pigeon-toed—in fact, he's just a little **duck-footed**, and it may be a good thing."

I don't know how to use this adjective in "Don't stand ___" though.

Comment: And as the definition suggests, *splay-footed*, which is probably more common.

Answer (score -1):

Definition of slue-foot [or -footed] as in "Slue-foot Sue" who was Pecos Bill's 1st wife...
: having big, clumsy, or turned-out feet, sometimes spelled slew (nautical)
Best wishes,
Al